# Setting up a working internet connection in solaris 11

Tags: networking, unix, internet-connection, solaris

the title of this post states most of my problem. I am trying to connect to the internet for like 3-4 hours. But for being a total newbie at unix environment I failed pretty badly. How can I configure a working internet connection in solaris 11? After trying for so long I finally managed to go this far----
Seems ok to me. But whenever i try to open a webpage say http://www.google.com, it says "failed to connect to the internet, try again!".

I know I have messed it up somehow, but please somebody help me out. I thorough instruction can save my life here. I am posting it from windows as I can't access internet from solaris.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but I wanted to let you know that you should really put a specific question somewhere in your post in the future [per the SuperUser posting guidelines](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask). That being said, could you open up your terminal (that black box in the menu bar up top), run the `ifconfig` command, and edit your post with the output?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason too, I would have your Network Preferences' `IPv4 IP` option set to `DHCP assigned`. Let me know if that does anything.

Comment: How is the network configured when running Windows ?

Comment: please stay with me here. Its taking ridiculously long to go back check and come back and post here :)

Comment: @ubomb dhcp enabled is not working im afraid. the network sign becomes yellow and the wired net0 connection becomes "not connected" whenever i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself

```
$ sudo sysconfig configure
```

After that reconfigured my system along with the internet and that fixed it. Thanks for all the responses.